# A model for recognizing suspicious user activity on a forum

Tags: python, data-science-model

I have a log of user actions on my website. Some users were blocked for spamming manually. This is also shown in the log.

Here is an example of the dataset:

```
11a|mike|comment
1pm|josh|comment
1pm|andy|comment
1pm|andy|comment
1pm|josh|comment
1pm|andy|comment
1pm|mike|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|comment
2pm|andy|get_block
```

I need to automate the process based on the data I already have.

What method can I use to solve this problem (time series, survival analysis, etc.)?
Which Python framework is designed to solve such problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Time series** and **survival analysis** are both possible options. Time series would be used to find temporal patterns, while survival analysis would help predict the time until a user is blocked. You could also use [**anomaly detection**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) to identify unusual patterns or you could treat it as a [**classification problem**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification), if you have labeled events.

Regardless of the method, you'd have to do some **feature engineering** first (e.g., calculating the number of comments by each user given a time frame).

Also, ideally, you'd like to periodically review some of the model's decisions to check whether it's performing well.

As for frameworks, your choice will depend on the model, but some of the most popular ones are scikit-learn, statsmodels, and prophet.